# Solana: get NFT supply cap?

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

How can I be sure a token will not be minted anymore?

In this tutorial we can see a `maxSupply` specified. How do I retrieve this value give a mint address?

https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#mint-the-nft

```
  await actions.mintNFT({
    connection,
    wallet: new NodeWallet(keypair),
    uri: 'https://34c7ef24f4v2aejh75xhxy5z6ars4xv47gpsdrei6fiowptk2nqq.arweave.net/3wXyF1wvK6ARJ_9ue-O58CMuXrz5nyHEiPFQ6z5q02E',
    maxSupply: 1
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the next step would be the following ->

```
await setAuthority(
  connection,
  fromWallet,            // Payer of the transaction fees
  mint,                  // Account 
  fromWallet.publicKey,  // Current authority 
  0,                     // Authority type: "0" represents Mint Tokens 
  null                   // Setting the new Authority to null
);
```

The setAuthority function will revoke minting privileges and ensure that you can not create additional tokens of this type. Note that this action cannot be undone.

resource: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/web3-sdks/how-to-mint-an-nft-on-solana
,
[https://spl.solana.com/token#:~:text=ThawAccount%20instruction.%20The-,SetAuthority%20instruction,-can%20be%20used](https://spl.solana.com/token#:%7E:text=ThawAccount%20instruction.%20The-,SetAuthority%20instruction,-can%20be%20used)

Comment: To go with that, you can check on the current token supply using the `getTokenSupply` RPC method: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokensupply

Comment: What if I don't have the authority? How to get the maxSupply of a mint from someone else?